# How to compare two arrays and get only the common value in Mule 4 - Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to compare two arrays and get only the common values in Mule 4 dataweave

Input:

```
 array1 = ["aaa", "bbb"]
 array2 = ["aaa","ccc","ddd"]
```

Output:

```
 Result: ["aaa"]
```

I tried "--", diff but both didn't gave me expected result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
var array1 = ["aaa", "bbb"]
var array2 = ["aaa","ccc","ddd"]
output application/java
---
array1 reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (array2 contains item) acc + item else acc
```